# jQuery content slider with customisable grid of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, slider

Does anyone know of a jQuery content slider (not just an image slider) that allows you to specify a grid of elements?

As an example, this is the sort of grid that I'm after:

http://cl.ly/image/0O213C1n2b0s

You can see that it's a 2x2 grid. With the controls, when someone clicks on a 'next' link, it should scroll to show the next 4 elements. I'd like to be able to have multiple instances on a page, each having different grids (I may be 3x2, 2x2, 4x1 on the same page)

Also, as an added caveat, I need this to be responsive.

First question is; does anyone know of a solution that already exists which would fit my requirements? If not, that leads to my second question; would anyone like to help me write such a thing? I'm relatively savvy with javascript (more specifically jQuery if I'm being absolutely honest) but by no means an expert.

I've done a fair amount of googling, but came up short. Hopefully someone is way ahead of me and has already written something along these lines.

What say you, Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this:

[jQuery grid syle slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-grid-style-slider/1204040)